# Does atos not supports armv7s?

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports

I tried to symbolicate an iOS crash report sent from Apple.

```
atos -arch armv7s -o APP_BINARY_PATH 0x0006a23c 0x35000 + 217660
```

And I got below error.

```
> atos: Unknown architecture: armv7s
```

I make sure that binary includes armv7s build by using otool.

Does atos not supports armv7s?

When I changed -arch argument to armv7, it works fine.

My Xcode version is 4.5.2.

Comment: Does the binary in question contain ARM7S code?

Comment: @Till you'd get a different error message if it didn't: `atos cannot load symbols for the file APP_BINARY_PATH for architecture armv7s`.

Comment: Does the problem fixed? I met another problem that the atos command gives me the wrong position in my code. I think i find the right dsym file and the right atos path, the result looks fine, but I can't find the function it gives me. Can you help me? Have you ever met the same problem? @Kerni

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use the atos version that is part of Xcode. You can find it here: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/atos`

Comment: Or better yet, `xcrun atos`.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, I still get:
atop cannot load symbols for the file ... for architecture armv7s.
If I try with

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/atos -arch arm7s -o * -l ...
```

I get

> [invalid usage]: Unknown architecture: "(null)"

If I finally try:

```
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/atos -arch arm64 -o * -l
```

I get returned the second value I submitted with the name of my app.

xrun behaves the same, as well as simply using atos.