# How to symbolicate arm64 acrhitecture iOS app crash

Tags: ios

I have tried to symbolicate 64 bit iOS app crashes using `atos` command line using terminal but it is not working for architecture `arm64`.

```
$ atos -arch arm64 -o myApp.app/myApp.app 0x0000000100eda4d0
```

> atos: Unknown architecture: arm64

Can you please suggest what could be reason for not detecting `arm64` platform.

Comment: may this link help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227747/does-atos-not-supports-armv7s

Comment: How about `xcrun atos ...`?